# Validating and revoking the constructor of a class

Tags: c#

I am applying validation logic in the constructor and returning if that fails. But, still the instance is created. How can i make sure that if a logic fails, the ctor should not create the instance.

```
class Car
{
    public readonly int maxSpeed;
    private int currSpeed = 99;
    public Car(int max)
    {
        if (max > 50)
            return;
    }
    public Car()
    {
        maxSpeed = 55;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should throw an exception in the constructor if validation fails.

Various framework classes do that, look at the [System.String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131424.aspx) or [System.DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2xf7zzk.aspx) constructors for example.

Comment: hmm...shit man....I used the similar manner while working on a WPF project...Guess inheritance taking a toll on me ;-)

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say thanks. You are the second user in my RAM after Jon Skeet ;-)

Comment: @Pankaj Upadhyay: thanks for the kudos! Although that is probably a bit too much of an honour.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Car GetInstance(int max)
{
    if (max > 50)
        return null ;

    return new Car(max); 
}
```

Comment: not sure why the -1 from someone.  Although this isn't a factory pattern I normally use this could be acceptable in some applications where the reason for failure wasn't important but a high number of failures would be common.

Comment: I didn't do the -1, but I wouldn't advise using this approach.  I prefer the [clean code](http://www.amazon.ca/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882) idea of never returning null from a function, and this violates that.  If a high number of failures is common so you want to avoid exceptions, I would prefer rewriting this as `public static bool TryGetInstance(int max, out Car instance)` just because it's a lot more explicit, and it's idiomatic C#.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Falcon's answer of throwing an exception in the constructor, but if you want to avoid throwing exceptions, you can do this:

```
public static bool TryGetInstance(int max, out Car instance)
{
    instance = null;
    if(max > 50)
    {
        return false;
    }

    instance = new Car(max);
    return true;
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally you can use one of the following (these are the ones I know...)

0 - Since constructors can't return a value, create a public var and use it to indicate the state of the object. (this line was edited based on feedback below)

1 - raise exception in the constructor (not very good for several reasons)

2 - use a factory to create the class for your client

Also,see this thread:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/31867966/how-to-return-null-from-c-class-constructor-after-a-validation.aspx

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/51062/constructor-parameter-validation-in-c-best-practices

Comment: Do constructors return the instance in hidden manner ??. If that's the case then returning null would be a better option

Comment: I do not believe constructors in C# can return null.

Comment: thanks gents for pointing out the mistake, I changed my suggestion for point 0.